# MySQL - combine 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 separate tables in MySQL (I'm using Sequel Pro on a Mac) with the exact same column names. Is there a function to join these tables and create one table with the same headers?

Example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Table 1

a   b   c
1   2   4
3   3   1

Table 2

a   b   c
3   2   1
8   4   2

Output

a   b   c
1   2   4
3   3   1
3   2   1
8   4   2
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can export table 2, and then use that query (rewrite it a bit) to insert all the data in your first table.

Comment: Have you tried anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table table_3 as
select * from table_1
union
select * from table_2
```

If you don't want to keep duplicates.

UNION ALL if you do want to keep duplicates.

Comment: No, I think I want "union all" because I *do* want duplicates, the a-b-c were the headings for the columns not rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS
select *
from table1
cross join table2
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE new_table_name AS
select * from table1
union all
select * from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `UNION` function, not a `JOIN`:

```
CREATE TABLE Table3 like Table1;

INSERT INTO Table3
SELECT * FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Table2;
```

But you just want to insert the values from one table into another:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (a, b, c) SELECT a, b, c FROM Table2
```

Then delete the second table:

```
DROP Table2;
```